# .Net Core Jquery Validation Showing Up Error Message

Tags: jquery, .net, ajax, asp.net-core

I can't see validation messages in here. Where I did fault I couldn't see It works on server side, I can validate on backend but I couldn't show up these validation messages to user
[image]

This is my Modal

```
    [DisplayName("Kategori Adı")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage ="{0} boş geçilmemelidir.")]
    [MaxLength(50,ErrorMessage ="{0} {1} karakterden büyük olamaz.")]
    [MinLength(3, ErrorMessage = "{0} en az {1} karakterden oluşmalıdır.")]
    public string CategoryName { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("Kategori Açıklama")]
    [MaxLength(50, ErrorMessage = "{0} {1} karakterden büyük olamaz.")]
    [MinLength(3, ErrorMessage = "{0} en az {1} karakterden oluşmalıdır.")]
    public string CategoryDesc { get; set; }
```

This is my View

```
 @model Mvc.Entities.Dtos.CategoryAddDto
<head>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="~/jquery-validate/jquery.validate.js"></script>
    <script src="~/jquery-validation-unobtrusive/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js"></script>

</head>
    <div class="modal-body">
                        <form action="Add" id="form-category-add" method="post">
                            <input type="text" id="isvalid" value="False" />
                            <div asp-validation-summary="All" class="text-danger" id="validation-summary" aria-hidden="true">
    
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label asp-for="CategoryName"></label>
                                <input type="text" name="CategoryName" class="form-control" asp-for="CategoryName" value="" />
                                <label class="text-danger" asp-validation-for="CategoryName"></label>
                            </div>
    
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label asp-for="CategoryDesc"></label>
                                <input type="text" name="CategoryDesc" class="form-control" asp-for="CategoryDesc" value="" />
                                <label class="text-danger" asp-validation-for="CategoryDesc"></label>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
```

Comment: I think it's difficult to troubleshot on these code snippet as they looked no issue. I posted my testing code below, I think you may check if the taghelper has added.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there may be something wrong with the configuration. I created a new asp.net core 3.1 mvc project. And I created a new Controller, Create.cshtml and category model. But I think it may comes from the tag helper. Pls check if theres `@addTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers` in your `_ViewImports.cshtml`

[image]

Controller：

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using WebApplication1.Models;

namespace WebApplication1.Controllers
{
    public class HelloController : Controller
    {
        public IActionResult Create()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult Create([Bind("CategoryName,CategoryDesc")] Category cate)
        {
            return View(cate);
        }
    }
}
```

My view and model are bascially copied from your code snippet.
Create.cshtml I used cdn, but bascially, these scripts are included in the `_ValidationScriptsPartial.cshtml`：

```
@model WebApplication1.Models.Category

<head>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.19.3/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validation-unobtrusive/3.2.12/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>

</head>

<div class="modal-body">
    <form action="Create" id="form-category-add" method="post">
        <input type="text" id="isvalid" value="False" />
        <div asp-validation-summary="All" class="text-danger" id="validation-summary" aria-hidden="true">

        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="CategoryName"></label>
            <input type="text" name="CategoryName" class="form-control" asp-for="CategoryName" value="" />
            <label class="text-danger" asp-validation-for="CategoryName"></label>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="CategoryDesc"></label>
            <input type="text" name="CategoryDesc" class="form-control" asp-for="CategoryDesc" value="" />
            <label class="text-danger" asp-validation-for="CategoryDesc"></label>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-primary" />
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

Model Category.cs：

```
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace WebApplication1.Models
{
    public class Category
    {
        [DisplayName("Kategori Adı")]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "{0} boş geçilmemelidir.")]
        [MaxLength(50, ErrorMessage = "{0} {1} karakterden büyük olamaz.")]
        [MinLength(3, ErrorMessage = "{0} en az {1} karakterden oluşmalıdır.")]
        public string CategoryName { get; set; }
        [DisplayName("Kategori Açıklama")]
        [MaxLength(50, ErrorMessage = "{0} {1} karakterden büyük olamaz.")]
        [MinLength(3, ErrorMessage = "{0} en az {1} karakterden oluşmalıdır.")]
        public string CategoryDesc { get; set; }
    }
}
```

testing result:

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for your effort. Can I ask about where did you put your code that cals _ValidationScriptsPartial.cshtml file? head tag or under body?

Comment: I used a newly created asp.net core3.1 MVC project, and I didn't do any configuration about _ValidationScriptsPartial.cshtml.  And I think what related to it is the last line `@RenderSection("Scripts", required: false)` before </body> of _Layout.cshtml